# On asp:Table Control how do we create a thead?

Tags: c#, syntax, html-table, tablesorter, asp.net-3.5

From an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tableheaderrow.aspx) on the subject, we can see that we create a `TableHeaderRow`that contains `TableHeaderCell`s.

But they add the table header like this:

```
myTable.Row.AddAt(0, headerRow);
```

which outputs the HTML:

```
<table id="Table1" ... > 
<tr> 
    <th scope="column" abbr="Col 1 Head">Column 1 Header</th>
    <th scope="column" abbr="Col 2 Head">Column 2 Header</th>
    <th scope="column" abbr="Col 3 Head">Column 3 Header</th> 
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td>(0,0)</td>
    <td>(0,1)</td>
    <td>(0,2)</td>
</tr>

...
```

and it should have `<thead>` and `<tbody>` *(so it works seamless with tablesorter)* :)

```
<table id="Table1" ... > 
<thead>
<tr> 
    <th scope="column" abbr="Col 1 Head">Column 1 Header</th>
    <th scope="column" abbr="Col 2 Head">Column 2 Header</th>
    <th scope="column" abbr="Col 3 Head">Column 3 Header</th> 
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr> 
    <td>(0,0)</td>
    <td>(0,1)</td>
    <td>(0,2)</td>
</tr>
    ...
    </tbody>
```

the HTML aspx code is

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" />
```

**How can I output the correct syntax?**

---

**Just as information**, the `GridView`control has this built in as we just need to set the Accesbility and use the `HeaderRow`

```
gv.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
gv.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
gv.HeaderRow.CssClass = "myclass";
```

but the question is for the `Table` control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found a way to do this, we do need to use our own controls that inherit from the base control, for example a `Table`

```
public class myTable : System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table
{
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        Table table = Controls[0] as Table;

        if (table != null && table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            // first row is the Table Header <thead>
            table.Rows[0].TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
            // last row is the Footer Header <tfoot> (comment for not using this)
            table.Rows[table.Rows.Count - 1].TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;

            FieldInfo field = typeof(WebControl).GetField("tagKey", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            foreach (TableCell cell in table.Rows[0].Cells)
                field.SetValue(cell, HtmlTextWriterTag.Th);
        }
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
}
```

works fine with `DataGrid` as well

```
public class myDataGrid : System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid 
{
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        Table table = Controls[0] as Table;

        if (table != null && table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            // first row is the Table Header <thead>
            table.Rows[0].TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
            // last row is the Footer Header <tfoot> (comment for not using this)
            table.Rows[table.Rows.Count - 1].TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;

            FieldInfo field = typeof(WebControl).GetField("tagKey", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            foreach (TableCell cell in table.Rows[0].Cells)
                field.SetValue(cell, HtmlTextWriterTag.Th);
        }
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
}
```

then for example you just need to use it instead the base control:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        myGridView dg = new myGridView();
        dg.DataSource = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" };
        dg.DataBind();

        ph.Controls.Add(dg);
    }
}
```

and in aspx page, just add a place holder like:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph" runat="server" />
```

> [full example in pastebin](http://pastebin.com/mzwdmsvA)

Answer (score 1):

Please note: this is a VB.net answer to the same question, you could simply convert this to C# using any number of free online converters.

Create a simple HTML table with a thead & tbody. I specifically needed a thead element for the jQuery tablesorter plugin.

```
    Dim ta As Table
    Dim thr As TableHeaderRow
    Dim thc As TableHeaderCell
    Dim tr As TableRow
    Dim td As TableCell

    ta = New Table
    ' make a header row & explicitly place it into the header section
    thr = New TableHeaderRow
    thr.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
    ' add cells to header row
    thc = New TableHeaderCell
    thc.Text = "ID"
    thr.Cells.Add(thc)
    thc = New TableHeaderCell
    thc.Text = "DESC"
    thr.Cells.Add(thc)
    ' create a data row & append cells to it
    tr = New TableRow
    td = New TableCell
    td.Text = "101"
    tr.Cells.Add(td)
    td = New TableCell
    td.Text = "VB.net is not so bad."
    tr.Cells.Add(td)
    ' append the header & row to the table
    ta.Rows.Add(thr)
    ta.Rows.Add(tr)

    ' add the new table to your page
    Page.Controls.Add(ta)
```

Comment: you're didn't got the question, if you have a data source, why would I want to do everything by hand? calculate the number of columns, the rows, etc, if I could simply do `myTable.DataSource = myDataSource;` and all I want is to create the `<thead>` as everything else is already there!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a million years late on this but I just needed to do the same. It handles much the same as the grid view.

```
        foreach (var item in dynamicData)
        {
            var c = new TableHeaderCell()
            c.Text = item.Whatever;
            hr.Cells.Add(c);
        }
        //This is the important line
        hr.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

        MyTable.Rows.Add(hr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest that you try the declarative syntax, but I now know what you mean; the following code...:

```
<asp:Table runat="server" ID="sometable">
    <asp:TableHeaderRow BackColor="#ADD9E6">
        <asp:TableHeaderCell ID="DataHeader" CssClass="Heading1" Text="Data Header" />
    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>Data</asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

... produced similar results to what you posted:

```
<table id="sometable" border="0">
<tr style="background-color:#ADD9E6;">
    <th id="DataHeader" class="Heading1">Data Header</th>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Data</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Perhaps a custom control could be created to solve your problem? Seems like overkill, but at least you can control what the generated output is.

Another option is to inherit from the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table` class, and [override how the table is rendered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.rendercontents.aspx).

Comment: I can't use the declarative syntax :( it's a dynamic table, only on RunTime I know how many what what is the columns all about... this idea uses an XML that is generated by a designer to create the "Grid"

Answer (score 0):

If you could use a DataGrid when you name the columns in the template it will produce a thead and tbody appropriately.

Comment: DataGrid does not do it by default

Answer (score 0):

Add `TableSection="TableHeader"` to the TableHeaderRow like:

```
<asp:TableHeaderRow ID="TableHeaderRow2" 
 runat="server" TableSection="TableHeader" >
```