# change thead tags created by HtmlTextWriter

Tags: c#, html, htmlwriter

I am using C#'s HtmlTextWriter to create a HTML table.
When I loop trough creating my table header it creats it in this format

`<tr><th>colname</th><th>colname</th><th>colname</th><th>colname</th></tr>`

I want the `<tr>` to say `<thead>` and the `<th>` to say `<td>`.

How do I program HtmlTextWriter to change the tag values?

Here's my loop for creating the header.

```
public void BuildHTMLTable(DataTable dt)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter w = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    Table tbl = new Table();
    tbl.ID = "example";
    tbl.CssClass = "display";
    tbl.CellSpacing = 0;

    TableHeaderRow thr = new TableHeaderRow();
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        TableCell th = new TableCell();
        th.Text = col.Caption;
        thr.Controls.Add(th);
    }
    tbl.Controls.Add(thr);

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        foreach (var value in row.ItemArray)
        {
            TableCell td = new TableCell();
            td.Text = value.ToString();
            tr.Controls.Add(td);
        }
        tbl.Controls.Add(tr);
    }

    TableFooterRow tfr = new TableFooterRow();
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        TableCell th = new TableCell();
        th.Text = col.Caption;
        tfr.Controls.Add(th);
    }
    tbl.Controls.Add(tfr);
    tbl.RenderControl(w);
    tableString = sw.ToString();
}
```

Comment: To change `th` to `td`, use `TableCell` instead of `TableHeaderCell`

Comment: Excellent, half way there! Thanks.

Comment: You say you're using `HtmlTexWriter` but I can't see it anywhere in your code?

Comment: Added the whole method for you. I felt the only necessary part was the header loop. I hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: Also, try `thr.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;`, you can look here if you need something further: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045017/on-asptable-control-how-do-we-create-a-thead or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052003/htmltable-htmltablerow-htmltablecell-creating-thead-tbody-and-tfoot

Comment: @Frantumn updated my comment - do either of those pages help?

Comment: @Frantumn please don't "fix" your question's code with suggestions made in comments as you go - it makes it very hard to follow your problems. Of course this does not include adding extra code for clarification!

Comment: @entropic that didn't do it either.